# ListView's refresh command not working with binded IRelayCommand

Tags: xamarin, mvvm, xamarin.forms, exrin

I created a form with listview and ISingleOperation fo data refresh.

Then i created command in ViewModel.

```
 public IRelayCommand LoadInvoicesCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return GetCommand(() => Execution.ViewModelExecute(new LoadInvoicesOperation(_model), 10000));
        }
    }
```

ISingleOperation works well and returns

```
new Result() { ResultAction = ResultType.None };
```

Refresh operation is bound well

```
RefreshCommand="{Binding LoadInvoicesCommand}"
```

But  refresh indicator "hangs" and not disapearing, what is wrong here?

Comment: Could you post the XAML of your Lisview?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to bind a second property from the `ListView` named [IsRefreshing](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/property/Xamarin.Forms.ListView.IsRefreshing/) to your ViewModel. This is a boolean property and is the one responsible to tell the `ListView` that the refreshing has started/completed.

An example of a ListView XAML

```
<ListView 
    VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
    IsPullToRefreshEnabled="true"
    RefreshCommand="{Binding LoadInvoicesCommand}"
    IsRefreshing="{Binding IsRefreshing, Mode=OneWay}"
    ItemsSource="{Binding YourItemSource}"
    ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ItemTemplate" />
```

Your ViewModel will need a public property called `IsRefreshing` and you will need to set this to `false` when you the refresh command has completed.